# Permission denied in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, shell

I have logged as root on Linux machine. Now trying to execute a binary file `test` of C++ but it produce an error "Permission denied". While I have given the permission to the binary (test) using `chmod +x test`.

Thanks

Comment: Check that you are root.

Comment: Is selinux on the box?  acl rules?

Comment: What is the output from `file test` ?

Answer (score 5):

If the file test is located on a separate mount point, and that mount point is mounted with the noexec flag, you will not be able to execute any binaries on it.

From the mount manpages:

```
noexec   Do not allow direct execution of any binaries on the mounted filesystem.
```

You can see what flags mount points are mounted with using the following command:

```
mount -l
```

Comment: I also suspect the same... by default, gcc will create the executable with +x permissions.

Answer (score 0):

If the binary `test` resides in the directory /dir1/dir2, do either of this (using absolute path):

```
/dir1/dir2/test
```

or navigate into the directory containing the program and use the `./` prefix (aka relative path)

```
cd /dir1/dir2
./test
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the command `ls -l /path/to/your/file` after `chmod +x /path/to/your/file`.

After that, check if the executable bits **x** are present, i.e., look to the first string that will be printed, it should be something similar to `-rwxrwxr-x`.

- If you don't have the three `x`, you have a problem with *chmod*. Probably you're not root.
- If you have the `x` but can't execute the program, the problem is
  with your call to the program. You should try to `cd` into the folder
  where the program is located and then execute it like
  `./program_name`.

Answer (score 0):

There's a command called "test" that might be in your path before your code is, which is why you'd type "./test" instead of just "test", which will be found in /usr/bin/test, probably.  ("which test" to find out on your system)

I don't know why /usr/bin/test would fail with that error, unless your test software takes parameters and you were giving the (on my system) /usr/bin/test a command that it couldn't do.

If it's not called test, and it's not a path issue, could you post some code and build details?

Comment: An old but still useful piece of advice is never to call a Unix program "test".